# SQLite selectionArgs not working

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I am having some kind of weird problem with my content provider: `selectionArgs` refused to work for a particular column.

**Insertion**

```
void saveFile(File file, Cursor cursor, Context context) {
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(file.getName() + " must be a file");
    }

    values.put(IS_DIRECTORY, false);
    // Some other values.put()
    context.getContentResolver().insert(FolderContract.CONTENT_URI, values);
}
```

And

```
void saveFolder(File file, String filesNum, Context context, int directTracks) {
        if (!file.isDirectory()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(file.getName() + " must be a directory");
        }

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(IS_DIRECTORY, true);
        // Some other values.put()
        context.getContentResolver().insert(FolderContract.CONTENT_URI, values);
}
```

**My Query**

```
@Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        Timber.w("onCreateLoader: ");
        String selection = String.format("%s = ? AND %s = ?",  FolderContract.IS_DIRECTORY, FolderContract.PARENT_ID);
        String[] selectionArgs = selectionArgs = new String[]{"0", args.getString(FOLDER_PATH)};
        return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), FolderContract.CONTENT_URI, null, selection, selectionArgs, null);
    }
```

I want the the query to return the rows with `FolderContract.PARENT_ID` column = `args.getString(FOLDER_PATH)` while the `FolderContract.IS_DIRECTORY` column will be false.

But the above query returns zero results however if I run it without the `FolderContract.IS_DIRECTORY` in the selection it returns all the matching 
results.The weird thing is that if I loop through the cursor, some of the returned rows has its `FolderContract.IS_DIRECTORY` column as 0 while 
 others is 1.

**ContentProvider**

```
@Override
    public Uri insert(@NonNull Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        final SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        long insertedRowId = database.insert(FolderContract.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        if (insertedRowId > -1) {
            Uri insertedUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI, insertedRowId);
            getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(insertedUri, null);
            return insertedUri;
        }

        database.close();
        return uri;
    }


    @Override
    public Cursor query(@NonNull Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {

        final SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = database.query(FolderContract.TABLE_NAME, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, sortOrder);
        cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
        return cursor;
    }
```

Please any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the type of the values in that column? It's not a string, is it?

Comment: @CL. No, it's not string but a boolean value.

Comment: So why are you comparing it with a string value?

Comment: That's because SQLite doesn't support boolean values. Instead it saved `false` as `0` and true as `1`.

Comment: But `0` or `1` are not string values.